# Drupal content type text value

Tags: nodes

I've created a content type that contains a form. In this form, there is a textfield that i want to make only readable + a specific value on it (if user A is editing this form, he can write on all textfields except this textfield that will contains : user A)

In the other side, I've a custom module that deals with users, so I have users with users ID, usernames..ect the username is the text that I want to automatically set on the content types textfield

I can't show you any code because as I said, it's a content type

Any help is great

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions).

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.

Comment: This module can make a textfield only readable ?

Comment: Yes. Do not grant the "Edit" or "Create" permission for the field (only the "View" permission).

Answer (score 0):

If this field is only used by modules and its existence doesn't make any change in your user's life , then you can make this field hidden in form . you also can fill its data using [rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) [easily](https://drupalize.me/videos/data-types-and-data-selection?p=1157) .